# grep for word, whitespace word

Tags: linux, grep

How does one do that in grep 3.1?

Searching for whitespace, then a word, then more whitespace works just fine, but grepping for a word, whitespace and then another word fails.

```
$ grep '[[:space:]]replication[[:space:]]' pg_hba.conf
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

$ grep 'host[[:space:]]replication' pg_hba.conf
$
```

The output of the first command demonstrates that there are lines in pg_hba.conf with the words `host` and `replication`.

My goal is to find the lines which have `host`, some whitespace and then the word `replication`.  Not, IOW, the line with "local" in it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts/code in your question(keep it up). Could you please do add samples of Input and expected output in your question to make it more clear. Kindly do add these details in your question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 but I did.  Didn't I?  There are two explicit grep commands: the first shows successful output, while the second show failed output even though searching for words that are shown to be in the file.

Comment: Actually I was saying about to post .conf file's contents but its up to you since you want answer specifically in `grep` only. How about changing your 2nd code to: `grep -E 'host[[:space:]]+replication' pg_hba.conf` once?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 it's a *big* file... :D

Comment: Not an issue, usually we request questioners to place samples for 5 to 6 lines only but in your case at least for me its looking clear now. How about trying my previous posts command once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 that worked.  Make your comment an answer, and I'll upvote it.  (Accept is after 24 hours in case a better answer arrives.)

Comment: Sure, you could try my 2nd(OR) answer also which I posted in my answer and could reply back on comment under my answer to discuss on same, cheers.

Comment: For questions about how to use an individual command at the Linux command line, please try https://superuser.com or [unix.se] - not here. It becomes a valid Stack Overflow question if you are trying to **write code** - for example, to spawn a separate process to run `grep`, or writing a shell script. See also various discussions [on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=shell+on-topic).

Comment: Question is getting closed with "Not a programming language question" reason, doesn't look correct at all IMHO, since its about `grep` and data manipulation NOT about how .conf file works.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel questions about how to use Unix tools are perfectly valid and extremely common on SO, it doesn't have to be about how to write code, they just have to contain a [mcve] with sample input, expected output and an attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples please try following `grep` code. There are 2 important things you are missing there, 1st: We better use `-E` to enable ERE and 2nd: we need to put `+` after `[[:space:]]` since its NOT 1 space occurrence its more than that. So your command would become like:

```bash
grep -E 'host[[:space:]]+replication' pg_hba.conf
```

***OR*** in case you want to match for exact word `host` then use like:

```bash
grep -E '(^|[[:space:]]+)host[[:space:]]+replication' pg_hba.conf
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With `awk` also you can try like following, considering if `host` is always coming in starting of line and `replication` string is always 2nd field/column in your Input_file.

```bash
awk '$1=="host" && $2=="replication"' Input_file
```

Comment: Second solution technically worked, but the original solution allowed me to add a `^` to the beginning of the search string (and that's what I really wanted).

Comment: @RonJohn, Good that it worked for you, in case you have made an edit to my **OR** code you could edit my answer and I will approve it. You could also try `awk` command because that should work in any version of it, cheers.

Comment: Well explained answer! Fyi @RonJohn consider using `[[:blank:]]` instead of `[[:space:]]` if you want to stay in line. It's a posix class for what is in PCRE `\h` (horizontal whitespace `[ \t]`). Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: @bobblebubble, Thank you sir. Yes you are right we could use `[[:blank:]]` also to tackle with addiotnal cases, that's very nice of you to mention the same, cheers.